# Let $2^A$ be the set of functions from a set $A$ to $\{0, 1\}$. Prove that there is a bijection between $2^A$ and the power set of $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I realize that there's already this thread:

[Prove that there is a bijection between the set of all subsets of $X$, $P(X)$, and the set of functions from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486830/prove-that-there-is-a-bijection-between-the-set-of-all-subsets-of-x-px-a)

I thought maybe there's a shorter proof?

> Let $f : A \to B$ be any function. Then the graph $Γ_f := \{(a, b) \in A \times B | b = f(a)\} \subseteq A \times B$ of $f$ is isomorphic to $A$.

Let $f: 2^A \to P(A)$ and $g: P(A) \to 2^A$. Then $2^A$ is bijective to $Γ_f \subseteq 2^A \times P(A)$ and $Γ_g \subseteq P(A) \times 2^A$ is bijective to $P(A).$ Since $Γ_g$ and $Γ_f$ are bijective and bijection is an equivalence realtion, $2^A$ is bijective to $P(A).$

Is it possible to argue like the above? Thanks.

edit:

Let $A = \{0, 1\}$. Subsets of $A$ can either contain an element of $A$ or not. Set up a bijection like so:

$\{0, 1\} \leftrightarrow (yes, yes)$

$\{0\} \leftrightarrow (yes, no)$

$\{1\} \leftrightarrow (no, yes)$

$\{\} \leftrightarrow (yes, no)$

If an element in the subset of $A$, then it corresponds to yes in the corresponding list. Now we can simply count the number of lists. Consider the set $\{yes, no\}$. There are $2$ choices for $yes$ and $2$ choices for $no$. So that there are $2^2$ lists of the form $(yes, no)$.

Comment: The graph of $f$ is not *isomorphic" to A, it's "equipotent" to A, or *bijectable with" A. "Isomorphism" implies a bijection that preserves not just size but some additional structure... which the graph of $f$ in general doesn't have. Your proof seems uneccesarily intricate, and looks incorrect. What are fhese functions $f$ and $g$? you don't define them! This is actually a simple statement, not hard to prove.

Comment: I just edited my post. Are you talking about a proof along those lines? Thanks.

Comment: Um, not really: $A$ is not equal to \{0, 1\}, it can be *any* set. But even when $A$ is the 2-element set, you would map $\{\} = \emptyset$ to (no, no), not to (yes, no) as you have it. I gave an answer that shows the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bijection $2^A \to \mathscr{P}(A)$:
$$
f \mapsto \{a \in A \mid f(a) = 1\}
$$
You can either (easily) show that this is 1-1 and onto, or show that the following function $\mathscr{P}(A) \to 2^A$ is its inverse:
$$
X \mapsto c_X
$$
where $c_X$ is the *characteristic function* of a set $X \subseteq A$, defined by: $c_X(a) = 1$ if $a \in X$, and $c_X(a) = 0$ if $a \notin X$.

Answer (score 0):

An element of $2^A$ is a characteristic function of a unique subset of $A$

Comment: Why can you say that there are no other functions in $2^A$than characteristic functions?

Answer (score 0):

If an element is sent to $0$ then it is not chosen. If it is sent to $1$ then it is.
This constitutes a bijection of described functions to subsets of $A$.