# Showing the power set is equinumerous to ${}^X2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that the power set of $X$ and the set of functions from $X$ to $2$ are equinumerous. I think the best way to do so is to define a bijection between the two, but I'm not sure how to construct such a function. How do I do this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486830/prove-that-there-is-a-bijection-between-the-set-of-all-subsets-of-x-px-a

Answer (score 2):

As  you said a bijection between the powerset $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of a set $X$ and the set of functions from $X$ to $2:=\{0,1\}$ is precisely what we need.

> We  start with a  small example. Let's consider $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and the set of subsets of $X$. We know there  are $2^{|X|}=2^3=8$  subsets  of  $X$ and we  *encode* each subset with the help of $0$ and $1$. We use $1$ to indicate if an element of $X$ is element of the subset and $0$ otherwise.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{array}{clc}
> \mathcal{P}(X)\qquad\qquad&\qquad 2^X&a\ b\ c\\
> \hline
> \emptyset\qquad\qquad&\qquad f_{\emptyset}&0\ 0\ 0\\
> \{a\}\qquad\qquad&\qquad f_{\{a\}}&1\ 0\ 0\\
> \{b\}\qquad\qquad& \qquad f_{\{b\}}&0\ 1\ 0\\
> \{c\}\qquad\qquad&\qquad f_{\{c\}}&0\ 0\ 1\\
> \{a,b\}\qquad\qquad&\qquad f_{\{a,b\}}&1\ 1\ 0\\
> \{a,c\}\qquad\qquad&\qquad f_{\{a,c\}}&1\ 0\ 1\\
> \{b,c\}\qquad\qquad&\qquad f_{\{b,c\}}&0\ 1\ 1\\
> \{a,b,c\}\qquad\qquad&\qquad f_{\{a,b,c\}}&1\ 1\ 1
> \end{array}

We see there are $2^3=8$ different possibilities to specify for each subset $S\subset \{a,b,c\}$ a function $f_S$ with
\begin{align*}
&f_S:\{a,b,c\}\rightarrow \{0,1\}\\
&f_S(x)=
\begin{cases}
1\quad& x\in S\\
0\quad& x\not\in S
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

We generalise this situation and formulate a bijection as follows:

> *Bijection:* For each subset $S\subset X$ we find a function $f_S:X\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> f_S(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1\qquad&\qquad x\in S\\
> 0\qquad&\qquad x\not\in S
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> on the other hand to each function $f:X\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ we specify a subset $T_f\subset X$ with
>
> \begin{align*}
> T_f=\{x\in X|f(x)=1\}
> \end{align*}

Comment: @Mark: Many thanks for granting the bounty! :-)

Comment: I’m struggling with the idea that all functions in $\{0,1\}^X$ must be of this form $f_S(x)$. Why can I be sure that there are no other possibilities to map $X$ to $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @philmcole: Take any map $f$ from $X\rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Each element from $X$ is mapped to either $0$ or $1$. If it is $1$ it is element of a subset $T_f$, if it is $0$ it is not element of this subset $T_f$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the function which associates to $f:X\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ the subset $X_f=\{x\in X, f(x)=1\}$