# Understanding bijection between $2^X$ and $P(X)$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to understand this [bijection between 2^X and P(X)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486830/prove-that-there-is-a-bijection-between-the-set-of-all-subsets-of-x-px-a?noredirect=1&lq=1) :

> Let us define $f: P(X) \rightarrow \{0,1\}^X$ by $f(\alpha) = g_{\alpha}$ where $\alpha \in P(X)$ and $g_{\alpha} : X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is defined by$$g_{\alpha}(x) =\begin{cases} 
>       1 & x \in \alpha \\
>       0 & x \in X-\alpha 
>    \end{cases}$$

In that question, everyone believes that $g_{\alpha}$ is a bijection...
I tried to show that this function is not injective with an example :

Lets denote:
$$ X = \{a,b,c\}$$ So:  $$P(X)=\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},\{a,b,c\},∅\}$$

We can conclude if ${\alpha}$ = $\{a,c\}$:
$$f(a)=1,f(b)=1$$
**But $a≠b$**
Am I wrong? If yes , could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: $g_\alpha$ is not (usually) a bijection; $f$ is.

Comment: $f$ is not evaluated at elements; it is evaluated at subsets. The *values* of $f$ are not zero or one, it is a function. In this case, the value of $f$ at the set $\alpha$ is the function $g_{\alpha}$; while $g_{\alpha}$ is not injective, that is not a problem. What you need to show is that if $\alpha\neq \beta$ then $g_{\alpha}\neq g_{\beta}$.

Comment: The underlying logic is you can define a subset by what "Is each element in or out of the set" from the base set.   So assign 1 to "In" and 0 to "out", and there's your bijection

Comment: Now I've got it. Thanks everyone.